# How to make a for loop that will go through functions without going through the same one twice

Tags: javascript, random, iteration, shuffle

I have some functions, like:

```
function functionOne() {
    /*
    code
    */
}
function functionTwo() {
    /*
    code
    */
}
function functionThree() {
    /*
    code
    */
}
```

How can I write code to call each of the functions, once each (i.e. without repeats), in a random order?

Comment: what code have you tried so far?

Comment: this question seems vague to me..

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr nothing yet

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put your functions in an array, randomise the array and then iterate through it:

```
var functions = [
function () {  alert("function 0");  },
function () {  alert("function 1");  },
function () {  alert("function 2");  },
function () {  alert("function 3");  },
function () {  alert("function 4");  }
    ];

functions.sort(function() { return 0.5 - Math.random() });

for (var i=0;i<5;i++) {
    console.log(i);
    functions[i]();
}
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a7kEM/)

Comment: How would I do this as a function instead of an alert? Or where is the function?

Comment: The `alert(...);` is the body of the function. Replace it with whatever code you choose. Just make sure you leave the enclosing braces intact.

Comment: So replace `alert("function 0");` with `functionOne()`?

Comment: That would be one way, or you could simply take the body of `functionOne()` and place it where `alert(...);` is and save yourself a function call.

Comment: Or, you could simply say `var functions = [ functionOne, functionTwo, `...etc.  (Note the lack of parens after the function names.  `()` makes JS call the function, and you want the functions themselves at this point, not the result you'd get from calling them.)

Comment: Shuffling a collection by sorting with a random comparator is a bad idea. It's far better to use the [Fisher Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle).

Answer (score 0):

this function should work:

```
 function randCall(){
      var array = [1,2,3];
      while(array.length > 0){
          var rand = (Math.random*array.length)|0; //converts to an Integer value
          switch(array[rand]){
             case 1:
                  functionOne();
                  break;
             case 2:
                  functionTwo();
                  break;
             case 3:
                  functionThree();
                  break;
          }
          array.splice(rand, 1);
      }
 }
```

hope this works and helps.